# Estou tentando usar o if com o char, mas não está dando certo e não sei como resolver

Tags: java, if, char

Estou tentando usar o if com o char, mas não está dando certo e não sei como resolver

./Main.java:18: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
if (c == "A")

first type:  char
second type: String
./Main.java:22: error: bad operand types for binary operator '=='
if (c == "P")

first type:  char
second type: String

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leia = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Informe o carácter (A ou P)");
        char c = leia.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("Informe a nota da prova, trabalho e participação: ");
        float prova = leia.nextFloat();
        float trabalho = leia.nextFloat();
        float part = leia.nextFloat();
        float media = calcularmedia(prova, trabalho, part, c);
        System.out.println("A média é igual a " + media);
  }
    public static float calcularmedia (float prova, float trabalho, float part, char c)
    {
        float media = 0;
        if (c == "A")
        {
            media = prova + trabalho + part;
        }
        if (c == "P")
        {
            media = (prova * 3.0f + trabalho * 5.0f + part * 2.0f) / 10.0f;
        }
        return media;
    }
}
```

Tentei usar o if com char, mas fala que estou comparando um char com string e não da certo

Comment: Já tentou fazer `c == 'A'` (usando aspas simples) para definir o `A` como char e não como string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc está comparando um char com uma string

Troque as aspas duplas por simples

```
if (c == 'A')
{
  media = prova + trabalho + part;
}
```

Msm "A" sendo apenas uma letra, se está dentro de aspas duplas é uma string.